# Copy entire folder structure when converting haml files to html (using grunt)

Tags: javascript, haml, gruntjs

I'm using yeoman and grunt and trying to convert haml files to html files. All my .haml files are located inside `/app/source` and I want all my html files to be one level lower, inside `/app`. Converting a single file works fine, this is the code I'm using in my `Gruntfile.js``

```
    files: {
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/tester.html': '<%= yeoman.app %>/source/tester.haml',
    }
```

But I don't want to list every file separately so I tried something like this but it's not working:

```
    files: grunt.file.expandMapping(['<%= yeoman.app %>/source/*.haml'], '<%= yeoman.app %>/source/', {
      rename: function(base, path) {
        return base + path.replace(/.haml$/, '.html');
      }
    })
```

This code probably wouldn't work with any subdirectories inside `/source` either. So, any ideas how I should do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: [Building the files object dynamically](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically)

Further explanation:

```js
expand: true;                    //Enable options below
cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/source'; //Current working directory
src: '**/*.haml';                //All files under cwd, including sub-directories
dest: '<%= yeoman.app %>';       //Destination path prefix
ext: '.html';                    //Replace file's extension name
flatten: false;                  //KEEP folder structure
```

Use this piece of code to replace your original "files" property, GL.

Comment: BTW, in my code example, I don't think `ext` option is necessary when you're using a haml2html plugin, because this should be done automatically. My code example is more useful in "copy-kind" plugins.